# How do I get MEID and IMEI information using adb commands on Android 5.0?

Tags: android, adb

The only command that I know that works on other versions is "adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo" but it doesn't seem to work on Android 5.0.

Answer (score 19):

To get `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` you can do:

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1
```

If you have problems with parsing `service call` output check out https://gist.github.com/ktnr74/60ac7bcc2cd17b43f2cb

Or you can do it on the device side with this Windows one-liner:

```
adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 | grep -o '[0-9a-f]\{8\} ' | tail -n+3 | while read a; do echo -n \\u${a:4:4}\\u${a:0:4}; done"
```

Or in Linux:

```
adb shell 'service call iphonesubinfo 1 | grep -o "[0-9a-f]\{8\} " | tail -n+3 | while read a; do echo -n "\u${a:4:4}\u${a:0:4}"; done'
```

Comment: I should have specified on a non-routed device. Thank you for the response @Alex P.

Comment: I just checked and it turns out that this specific service call does not actually require elevated privileges.

Comment: It is dusturbing why would some a-hole -1 you for perfectly valid answer

Comment: Here is a workaround for all Android versions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37940140/1140682

Comment: Starting from which Android version does it work? Also, you forgot to mention what the bottom commands return you. Is it IMEI ? Is it the same as what we should get from this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getSubscriberId() ? Currently it seems the answer is "yes" for both, at least on Android Q. But then I wonder, why have others: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getImei() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId() ?