# Testing phone call service or wifi with appium in python

Tags: python, selenium, appium, android-uiautomator, selendroid

In python I want to know if i can test phone call service with appium so as Wifi or bluetooth .
the point is i can with appium press phone call button and dial number but how actually i can test that phone call is established ?
same is for bluetooth - wifi - phone pairing

one dumb way is to press dial button and compare dial screen with a presaved screen but this is only UI testing, not connection service testing.
if it can't be done with appium,do you know how it can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the call button via appium, you can check the call state via adb:

```
    >>> import subprocess
    >>> output = subprocess.check_output("adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep mCallState", shell=True)
    >>> print(output)
    b'  mCallState=0\n'
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25793470/7675174).